# Kendo UI Grid - Build Columns Dynamically

Tags: kendo-grid, dynamic-columns, kendo-ui-grid

I have an array with the list of column names, that needs to be displayed in the grid. So, while initializing the grid, I need to loop through each column in the datasource - and if that column is present in the Array, then I need to display it.

For example,

```
var ColumnNames = ["col1","col3"];
var dataSource = [ {
                    "col1": "a", 
                    "col2": "1", 
                    "col3": "11",
                    "col4": "1111"
                  }, 
                  {
                   "col1": "b", 
                   "col2": "2", 
                   "col3": "22",
                   "col4": "2222"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "col1": "c", 
                    "col2": "3", 
                    "col3": "33",
                    "col4": "3333"
                  },
                .....]
```

The grid should display only with the columns present in the array. Here, as shown below:

```
col1    col3
---------------
a        11
b        22
c        33
.......
```

​

The ColumnNames Array and dataSource actually comes from DB, based on the user selection. So, I can not hardcode column names. I tried various options (using column templates, foreach loops for building the model, etc) , but facing one or the other issue. Can someone help me out on this please?

​

Thanks in advance!

​

Regards

Neelima

Answer (score 0):

Tri This :

```js
var ColumnNames = ["col1","col3"];
var dataSource = [ {
                    "col1": "a", 
                    "col2": "1", 
                    "col3": "11",
                    "col4": "1111"
                  }, 
                  {
                   "col1": "b", 
                   "col2": "2", 
                   "col3": "22",
                   "col4": "2222"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "col1": "c", 
                    "col2": "3", 
                    "col3": "33",
                    "col4": "3333"
                  }]

$(document).ready(function(){
    createGrid();
})
function createGrid(){
  var columns =  generateColumns(dataSource);
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({   
      dataSource : dataSource,
      columns  :columns
  });
}

function generateColumns(_dataSource){
  if(_dataSource.length > 0) {
    return Object.keys(_dataSource[0]);
  } 
}




$("#btnUpdate").click(function(){
 var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
 grid.destroy();
 $("#grid").empty();
 dataSource = [ {
                    "col1": "a", 
                    "col2": "1", 
                    "col4": "1111"
                  }, 
                  {
                   "col1": "b", 
                   "col2": "2", 
                   "col4": "2222"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "col1": "c", 
                    "col2": "3", 
                    "col4": "3333"
                  }];
 createGrid();
                  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id = "grid">
</div>
<button id="btnUpdate">update</button>
```